# Aplicativo android sobrepor tela de bloqueio

Tags: android

Ola, tenho um aplicativo onde o usuário recebe uma tela de tempos em tempos que solicita confirmação se aceita ou não fazer um serviço.

Alguns desses usuários usam o celular com a tela de bloqueio ativada e reclamam que para responder tem que desbloquear o celular para só então responder.

Soube que alguns aplicativos conseguem sobrepor a tela de bloqueio para que o usuário responda, mas não faço idéia de como implementar isso no meu app, alguém poderia me dar uma luz, pq não encontrei nada no Google a respeito.
Desde já agradeço a todos.

Comment: Caso o usuário utilize PIN ou Desenho de segurança, não creio que isso seja possível, porque podem gerar falhas de segurança se deixar acesso ao teclado virtual.

Comment: Ola Carlos, não utiliza teclado não, somente uma tela de sim ou não.

Comment: Porque você não implementa com Notification? Podes personalizar e colocar os botões nela.

Comment: Boa cara, já é uma opção.

Comment: eu faria assim, ó: se precisa avisar de tempos em tempos, logicamente vai ter de usar um serviço, dai, como é um serviço, nele dá pra verificar se a tela tá bloqueada, e se tiver, pausar o disparo do aviso no serviço para esperar o usuario desblquear naturalmente a tela e então exibir o aviso pro cara, assim, resolveria o problema da usabilidade, salvo se o aviso tiver de ser exibido exatamente em um momento fixo especifico.

Comment: Armando obrigado pela dica, mas o usuario tem 20 segundos para responder ao chamado quando o app detecta q o serviço foi enviado para ele, dessa forma  não tenho como retardar o disparo do aviso, mas obrigado por responder.